# Full Calendar Remove border color on previous click

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have a calendar set up with full calendar IO and i have

```
function eventClicked (evnt){
  if(evnt.available > 0){       
    $('#date').val('date_'+evnt.start.format());
    $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
  }
```

}
For it show the user that they clicked on an event and then it goes into some html.  But the issue I am having is getting it to clear the red border around any of the previous clicked days in case the user changes his mind.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Before to set them to red, retrieve all of them through a common selector and set border-color none to all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every click event, set the border of all of the "day" elements to `initial` and then change the color of `this` "day".

```
function eventClicked(evnt){
  if(evnt.available > 0){
    //set all days to initial 
    $('.days-selector').css('border-color','initial');
    $('#date').val('date_'+evnt.start.format());
    $(this).css('border-color','red');
  }
}
```

Comment: this worked great i just had to switch  .days-selector to  .fc-day-grid-event